# Place elements inside a fixed element

Tags: html, css

I would like both the td's to have equal length and stay within the red border. But the text boxes go beyond it.

The outer div with black border has position set to 'fixed'. This was needed to centre that div in page.

Even when I set the td width to 50% each, it isnt working. I understand , it is because the main div has a fixed position. So how work it out in this case.

**CSS:**

```
.loginBox
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 450px;
    height: 210px;
    margin: auto;
background-image: url(file:///C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/box-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
border: 1px solid rgb(18, 18, 18);
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 24px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.inner
{
border:1px solid red;
margin:20px;
width:91%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="loginBox">    
  <div class="inner">
   <table width="100%">
    <tr>
     <td>
      Username
      <div><input type="text"/></div>
     </td>
     <td>
      Password
      <div><input type="text"/></div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: create a fiddle for it first

Comment: did you mean `position:relative;` instead of `display:relative;` ?

Comment: The problem doesnt appear in fiddle. But you can see the pic how it is.http://jsfiddle.net/94Hag/

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.inner td {
  width: 50%;
}

.inner td input{
  width: 100%;
}
```

**UDPATE:**

You can improve with:

```
.inner td {
    width: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.inner td input{
    width: 99%; /* decreased for border width */
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what is missing is a width of the input elements.
[Here (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/8fz2A/) is how I would do it (with further improvements):

CSS:

```
    .loginBox {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 24em;
        height: 10em;
        margin: auto;
        background-image: url(file:///C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/box-bg.jpg);
        background-repeat: repeat;
        border: 1px solid rgb(18, 18, 18);
        box-shadow: 0px 6px 24px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }
    .inner {
        border:1px solid red;
        margin:1em;
        display:relative;
        width:91%;
        padding: 0.2em;
    }
    .input {
        padding: 1%;
        float: left;
        width: 46%;
    }
    input[type=text] {
        width: 100%;
    }
    span.clear {
        clear: left;
        display: block;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="loginBox">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="input">Username
                <div>
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input">Password
                <div>
                    <input type="text" />
                </div>
            </div> <span class="clear"></span>

        </div>
    </div>
```

What I changed:

- replace table with div (table tag should be used for tables ;))
- create floating div containers for text input with padding (1%) and width (46%); Why a width of 46%? Because of the left and right padding of the two inputs.
- add clear element after floating divs to prevent floating outside of the surrounding div